# How to redirect on a very limiting hosting service

Tags: redirects

I need to create some new content which is the user getting their request routed to another site w/o them needing to know the ugly final URL. The user URL needs to be the simple easy to recall string, for example, `example.com/snappy`.

So, I need to have a URL such as `http://example.com/snappy` redirect to something like `https://example.org/64g9sd3k96bhse38gmjdute.html`. If I were to use the technique I have used in the past I would create `/snappy/index.html` on the `example.com` system:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=https://example.org/64g9sd3k96bhse38gmjdute.html">
```

In this case though, I have a new situation where my `example.com` is hosted on `cloversites.com` which has "Websites made for people not programmers." They have such a canned system that the `index.html` cannot be created with the `meta` tag. I do have servers that can host web pages. I cannot move the existing `cloversites.com` content at this time.

I am looking for an out-of-the-box solution until all of the existing content can be moved in house.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use javascript anywhere on the page?

```
<script>
window.location.replace("http://example.com");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The options for creating a redirect from a specific document are:

- Create a document in that location and use a meta refresh tag.
- Edit the server configuration files such as *.htaccess* and put a redirect directive in

If the host that you are using does not provide any functionality for those, then you are out of luck.